# Intersection of two sets that contain other sets as elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

How would the intersection of $A=\{a, b, e, \{a, b, c, d\}, \{d, e\}\}$ and $B=\{a, b, c, f, \{a, d\}, \{d, e\}\}$ be defined? I've searched quite a few books but no luck so far.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange!  At this point, you just need to go back to the definition.  The sets inside the sets are confusing you, but you just need to think of those as elements.  The intersection of $A$ and $B$ is the set of all elements that they have in common.  But in this case, for example, $\{a,b,c,d\}$ is an element of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

The intersection of two sets, say $A$ and $B$, is defined to be the set of elements in both $A$ and $B$. So if $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{2,3,6,8\}$, then their intersection, denoted $A\cap B$ is
$$
A\cap B = \{2,3\}.
$$
Note that $2$ and $3$ are the only elements common to both $A$ and $B$.

Now, the only real difference for your particular $A$ and $B$ is that some of the elements are sets. Let's change our example. Say $A=\{1,2,\{3,4\}\}$ and $B=\{2,\{3,4\},\{6,8\}\}$. Note here that $\{3,4\}$ is an element of both $A$ and $B$. So $\{3,4\}$ is in their intersection. However, neither $3$ nor $4$ is an element of $A$ or $B$. Indeed, $3$ and $4$ are elements of the set $\{3,4\}$, which itself is an element of $A$ and $B$. So we see that
$$
A\cap B = \{2,\{3,4\}\}.
$$
See if you can identify the intersection of your sets, and feel free to ask if you need clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate on my comment and put it into an answer:

The definition of intersection is always the same.  The intersection of two sets $X$ and $Y$ is the set of all things that are in both $X$ and $Y$.

In other words
$z \in X \cap Y \iff z \in X \wedge z \in Y$.  It may be that $z$ is a set itself, but from $X$'s perspective it is just an element or not.

So in this case we can just look at each element in $A$ and ask if it is in $B$ and if it is, it will be in $A \cap B$.

- $a \in A$ and $a \in B$ so $a \in A \cap B$
- $b \in A$ and $b \in B$ so $b \in A \cap B$
- $e \in A$ but $b \notin B$ so $b \notin A \cap B$
- $\{a,b,c,d\} \in A$ but $\{a,b,c,d\} \notin B$ so $\{a,b,c,d\} \notin A \cap B$
- $\{d,e\} \in A$ and $\{d,e\} \in B$ so $\{d,e\} \in A \cap B$

At this point we are done.  We have checked which elements of $A$ are in $B$, it doesn't matter that $B$ has extra elements; for something to be in $A \cap B$ it must be in both.

Thus, we see that 
$A \cap B = \{a,b, \{d,e\}\}$

Answer (score 0):

What elements do the sets $A$ and $B$ have in common with each other? Remember that if $X=\{a\}$ and $Y=\{\{a\}\}$, then $X\cap Y=\emptyset$. This is because the set $X$ contains the element $a$ while the set $Y$ contains the element $\{a\}$. Thus the elements $a$ and $\{a\}$ are distinct.

Thus $A\cap B = {\{a,b,\{d,e\}}$. The intersection of the two sets that you have defined has cardinality $3$. Ryan displayed a method for finding the elements $A$ and $B$ have in common with each other. I hope this helps.